# Adding button handlers in loop

Tags: java, swing, event-handling

I have a few JButtons and am trying to add their action listeners in for loop but it gives null pointer exception, however no problem occurs if i add them one by one. I'm wondering what my wrong point is. Thanks.

```
JButton[ ] myButtonArray = { but1, but2, but3 };
ButtonHandler bh = new ButtonHandler();

for (JButton cur : myButtonArray) {    // I tried standard for loop as well.
    cur.addActionListener(bh);
}
```

Comment: Please post the stack trace containing the exception.

Comment: can you show the code for `ButtonHandler`? What does it extend?

Comment: there is no problem with ButtonHandler when I write like : but1.addActionListener(bh);

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Works perfectly fine for me.. Try this demo

[image]

```
package sof;

import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class CustomLayoutFrame{
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Custom Layout Frame");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        frame.setLayout(new GridLayout(3,1));

        JButton but1 = new JButton("Button1");
        JButton but2 = new JButton("Button2");
        JButton but3 = new JButton("Button3");

        JButton[ ] myButtonArray = { but1, but2, but3 };
        ButtonHandler bh = new ButtonHandler();

        for (JButton cur : myButtonArray) {    // I tried standard for loop as well.
            cur.addActionListener(bh);
        }

        frame.add(but1);
        frame.add(but2);
        frame.add(but3);

        frame.setSize(300, 150);
        frame.setVisible(true);
      }
}

class ButtonHandler implements ActionListener{
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
        System.out.println(((JButton)(arg0.getSource())).getText() + " Clicked !");

    }
}
```

Comment: It's same with mine, just my buttons have texts and they are placed onto layout..

Comment: okay thank you, it works well for me,too. let me get what my error is then.

Comment: you have added your buttons to the frame after adding handlers, I don't think so but might this be the problem ? Here s my example : http://pastebin.com/ApsmK29J

Comment: @berkantk : Put this line after initialising the buttons. `JButton[] bs = {left, right, center};` Adding the buttons to the frame is irrelevant in this context.

Answer (score 1):

And you did initialize `but1`, `but2` and `but3`? Because that's the most probable source of your nullpointerexception.

Comment: I did initialize them, Would not it give the same error if they were not when I added them classically ?

Answer (score 1):

I would guess at least one of your buttons is null - ie but1, but2, or but3 (or all of them) were not initialized.  Wh